# How to import maven dependencies from Nexus

Tags: java, gradle, nexus

I'm learning about Nexus Repository. And tried uploading an artifact to the maven repository on Nexus. How can I import it into my spring boot project? I have uploaded *.jar file via web interface to my repository. Also, I have tried it but it doesn't find my dependencies.

I got this error

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find mygroup.myartifact:0.0.1:.
```

Here's what I tried

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://nexusUrl:8081/repository/my-repo'

        credentials {
            username = 'admin'
            password = 'admin123'
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'

    implementation 'mygroup.myartifact:0.0.1'
    
    ...
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `'mygroup:myartifact:0.0.1'` (note the : instead of the .). This assumes that `mygroup` is the group and `myartifact` is the artifact name.

Comment: @@ It really works. I no longer see the above error. But if the dependency's group name is the same as the project's group name, how can I import it into the project?

Comment: For dependencies you always specify the complete coordinates, even when the group is the same as in the current project.